# when facing/ faced with

Tags: word-usage

I found this sentence in [an article](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chd/resources/stress/):

> *Stress is the physical and mental tension you feel when you are faced with change.*

Some people changed it into a TOEIC question with two possible answers regarding Reduced Relative Clauses. The two choices are *when faced with* and *when facing with*.

I checked the meaning and usage of *face* and found one example with *be faced with* in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/face#british-1-2-1):

> *You're faced with a very difficult choice there.*

This sentence also refers to the phrase *be faced with* in which the verb *face* is used in the Passive Voice and only in this voice, it goes with *with*. In other examples, I don't see any sentence with *face with*.

Therefore, some friends of mine have claimed that only in *be faced with*, the verb *face* will go with *with* and that *when facing with* is clearly a wrong answer. However, the phrase *when facing with* has appeared in a lot of books such as **The Gift - An Islamic Tale** of **IslamKotob**: *He had always been good at covering up his real feeling when facing with unexpected news.* Is this a right way to use *face with*?

I think both phrases can be used but when it comes to *a difficult question*, *when facing with* and *when faced with* seem right to me. In the first case, I have to *face with* a problem, while in the latter one, *I am faced with* it. What is the difference between the two phrases or is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two phrases you are looking for is

> when faced with
>   *Stress is the physical and mental tension you feel when you are faced with change.*
>
> when facing
>   *Stress is the physical and mental tension you feel when facing change.*

"When facing with" does not make sense since one "faces" something directly not "with" it

> *when facing* a wall
>   *when facing* a challenge

Please keep in mind that you are citing a translation in *The Gift - An Islamic Tale* which may have it's own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: According to what you have said, _with_ is only availabe in _be faced with_?

Comment: For your meaning of facing, I would say yes, "with" only works with "faced". If you used "facing" as a noun "When facing with plaster, humidity is a consideration" is a different meaning of "facing".

Comment: Can you explain to me that meaning of _facing with_? Give me some examples, please. @Peter

Comment: When you are "facing", you are covering something (placing a "face" on) with a material e.g. "facing a wall with plaster" is to cover a wall with a layer of plaster, sometimes also called a "skim coat". "Facing" also is used as a technical term in sewing and is a technique for finishing a edge.

Answer (score 1):

Facing with is not correct. You are either "faced with x" or "facing x" (without with with).